# I need a formula or function that will stop executing when criteria is met

Tags: excel

I have two columns. Column A has this formula `=IF($AA$1>=$BB$1,(H3/4),0)"`. Column B has this formula `=IF($AA$1<$BB$1, (H3/4),0)`.

BB1 is fixed number = 800

AA1 is variable that increases gradually after each user input.

Once AA1 is >= BB1 the data in column B cells (all cells) shifts to column A column cells. I don't want that!

I want to keep the populated cells in B column and start to fill the cells in A columns once AA1>=BB1

Comment: Formulas are live and will always change as the data changes.  You will need vba in a Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: But if you show us some test data and expected output, with the formula that is in AA1, we may be able to help with a formula that works.  There is not enough information here to make that possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with VBA. I know some C and Python. Any help with a VBA would be much appreciated

Comment: See my second comment.  We need more info.  What is the formula in AA1?

Comment: Can I attach an excel sheet here?!!

Comment: Please mock up the simplest data set and expected output that demonstrates the issue.  With all the pertinent data.  Many will not download, including myself, from the web.

Comment: [A] =IF($D$1>=$BB$1,(C3/4),0)    [B] =IF($D$1<$BB$1, (C3/4),0)      [C] user input (uint)       [D] = C1+C2+C3....     [BB1] = 800

So, If D is less than 800, column B1,B2,B3 should be filled. If D is more than 800 A4,A5,A6 should be filled withoout changing B1,B2,B3 values

Answer (score 0):

In A2(Assuming Titles:

```
=IF(SUM($C$1:C2)>=$BB$1,(H2/4),0)
```

In B2

```
=IF(SUM($C$1:C2)<$BB$1,(H2/4),0)
```

Now it reliant on the values in C as they progress and not the total value in `AA1`

Comment: The problem will still exist. Once the sum of C1,C2... becomes more than BB1 all the cells in B2 will move to A2. I want the already populated cells in B2 to remain in that column. A2 formula should start executing once the sum of C is above BB1 but B2 cells should not move to A2